# How to append multiple files in R

Tags: r, file, csv, append

I'm trying to **read a list of files and append them into a new file with all the records**. I do not intend to change anything in the original files. I've tried couple of methods.

**Method 1:** This methods creates a new file but at each iteration the previous file gets added again. Because I'm binding the data frame recursively.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

  #temparary data frame to load the contents on the current file
  temp_df <- data.frame(ModelName = character(), Object = character(),stringsAsFactors = F)

  #reading each file within the range and append them to create one file
  for (i in 1:length(files)){
    #read the file
    currentFile = read.csv(files[i])

    #Append the current file
    temp_df = rbind(temp_df, currentFile)    
  }

  #writing the appended file  
  write.csv(temp_df,"Models_appended.csv",row.names = F,quote = F)
```

**Method 2:** I got this method from [Rbloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-multiple-data-files-into-one-data-frame/) . This methods won't write to a new file but keeps on modifying the original file.

```
multmerge = function(){
  filenames= list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")
  datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=T)})
  Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y)}, temp_df)

}
```

Can someone advice me on how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it could look like this:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

DF <-  read.csv(files[1])

#reading each file within the range and append them to create one file
for (f in files[-1]){
  df <- read.csv(f)      # read the file
  DF <- rbind(DF, df)    # append the current file
}
#writing the appended file  
write.csv(DF, "Models_appended.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

or short:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

DF <-  read.csv(files[1])
for (f in files[-1]) DF <- rbind(DF, read.csv(f))   
write.csv(DF, "Models_appended.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this to load everything into one data set.

```
dataset <- do.call("rbind", lapply(file.list, FUN = function(file) {
  read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
}))
```

And then just save with `write.csv`.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could go ahead and use shell commands in R:

```
system2("cat", args = "*.csv", stdout = "appendedfiles.csv")
```

This would be for unix based systems; I'm not sure what you would do for windows.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your ListOfFileNames:

```
ListOfFileNames<-list.files(pattern=".txt")
outFile <- file("all.txt", "w")
for (i in ListOfFileNames){
    x <- readLines(i)
    writeLines(x, outFile) # in the link the 1st and last line are skipped
}
close(outFile)
```

Source: https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-Read-multiple-text-files-and-combine-into-single-file-td817344.html

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy answer with `rbind_list()` now!

For instance:

```
dataFiles = map(Sys.glob("*.csv"), read.csv)
```

or however you're reading the files into a list

```
dat = rbind_list(dataFiles)
```

and `dat` will be what you're looking for!

Comment: do you mean `data.table::rbindlist()`?

Comment: do you mean `dataFiles = purrr::map(Sys.glob("*.csv"), read.csv)`?

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows, it's easy to do this using the command prompt.

Start -> Run -> type "cmd" and hit return key

```
cd <path to folder>
copy /b *.txt <outputname>.txt
```

Concrete example:

```
cd C:\User\danny\docs\folder_with_txt files
copy /b *.txt concatenated.txt
```

Note that if you're changing drive letters to do this before cd

```
D:\> c:
C:\> cd C:\User\danny\docs\folder_with_txt files
copy /b *.txt concatenated.txt
```