# for loop to append files in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, automation

I'd like to write a line(s) of code to append multiple text files to each other to create one master list.

I used the following code to read all files.

```
myfiles <- list.files(path = filepath, pattern = "txt", full.names = TRUE)
```

but would like to create a for loop that will append (stacking the files on top of each other) x # of files into a Master text file that I could then ouput. 
Does anyone have a good loop procedure that could solve for this?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565199/how-to-append-multiple-files-in-r

Also, `rbind` can get inefficient for tons of files. `rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package will be more useful if you have A LOT of files to append.

Comment: `for( i in myfiles ) cat( readLines( i ), "\n", file = "master.txt", append = TRUE )`

Comment: You could also simply concatenate these files in your Bash via `cat` (which would concatenate all txt-files "row-wise" in the current working directory): `cat *.txt > output.txt`

Comment: @giraffehere that was helpful! - Question: How can I include the file names as a column using this code, for record keeping purposes?

Comment: @user3100446 In the `for` loop, add a column to the `currentFile` called "FromFile" or something like that and fill that column with the name of the file you are currently on. This would be `myFiles[i]` if you are using the same example as the other stack overflow question. Namely: `currentFile$FromFile <- myFiles[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `lapply` approach

```
myfiles <- list.files(path = filepath, pattern = "txt", full.names = TRUE)
list_files<-lapply(myfiles,function(x) read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors=F))
master_file<-do.call(rbind,list_files)
```